# Select top x% records

Tags: postgresql

Question is regarding how to get top `x%` of records according to their ratings.

For example I have a table with a few columns, one of which is `rating`:

```
rating            smallint
```

value of `rating` is always positive.

My goal is to select top `x%` of entries according to their rating.

For example, for top `20%`, if set of selected rows contains ratings like:

```
1,3,4,4,5,2,7,10,9
```

Then top `20%` would be records with range from 8 to 10 → records with rating 9 and 10.

I implemented it in Django but it takes 2 calls to DB and I believe it can be easily achieved via SQL in `PostgreSQL` by just one call.

Any ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the max rating available in the column is your base for max calculation.

Try this workaround:

```
select * from sample where rating >=(select max(rating)-max(rating)*20/100 from sample)
```

[Demo on fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sfR6BgiWT2j6phGxteJWqN/0)